# Possible way to interface a TFT touch panel with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, tft

I have a salvaged 40-pin TFT touch panel, and I am trying to see if I can control it with an Arduino. What are my chances of getting a driver for it ? I bought a RA8875 Driver Board from Adafruit, but the pin layout did not match.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you

[image]

Comment: You could see under the cover of the PCB and try to identify the part number of the controller. If its a standard one you might be able to find information about it. Though if this was from consumer hardware this is  not very likely. These parts often have custom chips or the labels on the chips is removed. And with an Uno you won't have much luck driving this. I guess the connections on the ribbon cable are all needed to drive it. The Uno most likely doesn't have enough pins for that.

Comment: I don't think the panel has a driver, that is the reason why I am looking for one.

Comment: Then I would ask what is on that PCB? But the result is the same. You need to find out what function each pin has. For that you can only look at the PCB. Reverse engineering is a very complex task. We cannot really help with that.